# React router wont trigger componentWillUnmount when the route is a sub-route

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am not seeing react-router unmount component when the route is a sub-route

So even if I switch between path/1 and path/2, componentWillUnmount never gets called for the instance of ComponentForRoute. Any suggestions? Is this how react-router is suppose to work? If so, any suggestions on handling route changes?

Tried using componentWillReceiveProps, but i guess its deprecated now?

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="path/:paramId" component={ComponentForRoute} />
</Router>
```

Comment: Do you only need to capture a route change event?

Comment: @Michele I have a page called `posts`, with sub pages like: `posts/new`, `posts/popular` etc, i am trying to reset state when i navigate between sub routes, current i am trying to reset with componentWillUnmount, but it doesnt seem to fire

Comment: Try using `ComponentDidUpdate(prevProps)`. You can test `this.props.location !== prevProps.location` (true if route has changed). Also, make sure to wrap the component with `withRouter`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, that worked out. I have one more question, I am using `async componentDidUpdate(prevProps){if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {await this.props.resetPosts(); this.props.fetchPosts(); }}`. Is this a bad approach to use async await for this ? Basically i am trying to wait for it to reset before it fetches the state for the new page.

Comment: You can do it. Even though you can get rid of `await` as it's the only call you perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
        //YOUR CODE HERE
    }
}
```

Also, component has to be wrapped with `withRouter`.